# CCAvenue integration - Hybrid Mobile App

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, ccavenue

Working on a hybrid app with ionic framework, planning to take build on both iOS and Android Platform. I need CCAvenue integration in this application. I know there are sdks available for both platforms. But I need an integration in hybrid way. Can I use the same web integration here?